# Is delaying a service in mule possible?

Tags: mule

I have a mule application that generates individual xml files and places them in a folder on the basis of a query, now I want to create aggregate reports which will consist data from various individual reports. Since services are run randomly, I want to make sure that I delay the generation of the aggregate report so that all the individual files exist before the service for aggregate report is called. Is it possible to set a timer on a service?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a candidate for aggregation:
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/asynchronous-message-processing-with-mule/

Answer (score 0):

You can use quartz for scheduling execution of flow in mule. User cron expression to customize the schedule for your needs. Here is an example of flow with quartz scheduler -

```
<flow name="resendFailedMessages">
<description>   
    "*/15 07-18 * * ?" run every 15 minutes from 7 am to 6 pm every day -->
</description>
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="hostRedeliveryJob" cronExpression="*/15 07-18 * * ?">
    <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
        <quartz:job-endpoint ref="redeliverToHost" />
    </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
<set-variable variableName="hostXML" value="#[payload]" />
<logger message="QUARTZ found message for host" level="INFO" />
<flow-ref name="webServiceCall" />
<flow-ref name="inspectWSResponse" />
<exception-strategy ref="retryExceptionStrategy" />
```

Also check this out - https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action-2e/blob/master/chapter07/src/main/app/quartz-config.xml

Comment: i am using mule 2.2.1, the issue is i need these services to run after a certain set of services, the code that runs now disptaches these jobs as threads, so i want certain threads to wait because they are dependent on certain threads. i need to find that one point where the individual reports get done. I tried doing it through java